# Compile error with NSCalendar unit flags with Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

The following code in Xcode 7 Swift gives the following compiler error, can anyone help?

```
   let unitFlags: NSCalendarUnit = .CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitDay | .CalendarUnitWeekday
```

error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Swift 2 the `OptionSetType` syntax and the `NSCalendarUnit` enumeration items have been changed

```
let unitFlags: NSCalendarUnit = [.Year, .Month, .Day, .Weekday]
```

Comment: thanks, couldn't find that easily